# how to fill field automatically in custom view from another field in another view in Odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I want to create clearance for a contract with some items with **3 attributes** of every item
I have 4 models:

1. Contract
2. Clearance
3. item
4. Clearance_item_rel

When I'm in the custom view of clearance model I select a contract
   from `Many2one` relation field

then try to create a `Clearance_item_rel` record in the
   `Clearance_item_rel` model.

When I click to create a `Clearance_item_rel` record it opens the
   custom view in a new window

I want to use the selected contract id in the first view to fill the `contract_id` field in `Clearance_item_rel` automatically as the user has just selected it in the first view

> P.S: `clearance_id` is created automatically as I create the
>   `Clearance_item_rel` record from clearance custom view But
>   `contract_id` doesn't do and this's my problem

Contract:

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    _name = 'clearance.contract'
    clearances = fields.One2many('clearance.clearance_item_rel', 
    'contract_id')
```

---

clearance:

```
class Clearance(models.Model):
    _name = 'clearance.clearance'
    contract = fields.Many2one('clearance.contract','Contract')
    items = fields.One2many('clearance.clearance_item_rel',clearance_id')
```

---

Clearance_item_rel:

```
class Clearance_item_rel(models.Model):
    _name = 'clearance.clearance_item_rel'
    contract_id = fields.Many2one('clearance.contract', 'Contract', ondelete='cascade')
    clearance_id = fields.Many2one('clearance.clearance', 'Clearance', ondelete='cascade')
    item_id = fields.Many2one('clearance.contract_item_rel', 'Item', ondelete='cascade')
    previous_quantity = fields.Integer()
    used_quantity = fields.Integer()
    total_price = fields.Integer()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer

You can do it via context on the field definition of the form view. **Sample code**:

```
<record id="clearance_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">clearance.view.form</field>
    <field name="model">clearance.clearance</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form>
            <field name="contract"/>
            <field name="items" context={'default_contract_id': contract}/>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

Where `default_contract_id` is the field name of `clearance.clearance_item_rel` prefixed with `default_` and `contract` is the value you want to fill the field with (in this case, the field name on `clearance.clearance` model). Note that `default_contract_id` uses quotes, while `contract` does not.

## Tips

Some other tips you might want to consider, as I see your code does not follow some Odoo naming conventions:

- M2o field names should be suffixed with `_id` as in `contract_id`
- O2m and M2m fields should be suffixed with `_ids` as in `item_ids` or `clearance_ids`